# how to assign database value to js variable and how to use that variable in js file

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

im using codeigniter in that one view file having form. one place textarea field come form js file like this

test1.js

```
var html = "<textarea class='gradx_code' id='gradx_code' name='button_gradient' style='display:block;'></textarea>";
```

im storing this textarea value in database by using name='button_gradient'

now i want to get this value from database and place at textarea value for updating this field for next time so im assign a database value to a js variable like this in view file

test1.php(view)

```
var textarea = '<?php echo $settings[0]->text_value ?>';
```

this textarea variable im useing in js file like this by using gradx_code in textarea id

test1.js

```
gradx.gx('#gradx_code').html(textarea);
```

but it is not work properly how i can do it help me

Comment: give us more code snippets..

Comment: "but it is not work properly"
what's wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

use it directly as php:

```
gradx.gx('#gradx_code').html('<?php echo $settings[0]->text_value ?>');
```

**EDIT:** Or you can load this value inside a cookie with php:

```
setcookie('text_value', $settings[0]->text_value, 0, '/');
```

,and call it wherever you need it with javascript:

```
gradx.gx('#gradx_code').html($.cookie("text_value"));
```

Comment: is it possible direct using php in js file. i have view file is different and js file is different

Comment: You must have  `gradx.gx('#gradx_code').html()` called in the php view file, inside `<script></script>` tags. They can exist on different `.php` files, as long as they get loaded on the same page.